# Intellij new switch expressions formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

Intellij formats my switch expression this way:

```
        String foo = switch ( bar )
            {
                case "one" -> "Narf";
                case "two" -> "Zort";
                default -> "Poit";
            }
```

And I want to be formatted in this way:

```
        String foo = switch(bar) 
        {
            case "one" -> "Narf";
            case "two" -> "Zort";
            default -> "Poit";
        }
```

I've tried multiple settings but none of them did the trick.

My checkstyle tasks keep failing every time Intellij formats a switch expression.

For now I've disabled the formatting on that lines but ideally, I would like to properly fix this.

Comment: Did you reformat code?

Comment: you can configure the code formatting or use a different code formatter in Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java

Comment: This cannot currently be done, probably because switch expressions follow expression formatting rules, and we usually configure idea to add extra indentation when an expression spans multiple lines. (Or it may be due to some other reason, I am not sure.) Go file a bug or feature request in the IntelliJ IDEA tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea